# Random black background "overlay" blocks Windows 10 search popup background

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, windows-search

[image: Example]

As shown on the screenshot, I have issue within this Windows installation which is related to dark background appearing inside the search popup and blocking the view. It sometimes is as low as on the screen, sometimes it takes around 50% of the popup's space, sometimes 90%. It disappears whenever I scroll the "latest" list with arrow key/scroll bar or restart explorer.exe/system. No idea when or why it starts reappearing, but it seems to be related to the number/variety of items in the "latest" list.

The problem usually appears after a while - at least few hours of using the system, but it could as well be few days and sometimes maybe weeks.

I tried temporarily uninstalling some applications related to task bar (EverythingToolbar, qtTabBar, HP Support Assisstant) but that didn't help. No further ideas as to how to debug this.

I don't have any custom Windows theme, I'm just using default dark theme with red accent.

Did anyone else encounter this issue? Does anyone know how to get rid of it permamently?

Comment: Does it happen when you boot in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc I don't know as the problem usually appears after a while and I can't afford to run the machine in safe mode for e.g. few hours or few days as this is where I'm doing m work.

Comment: That will be hard to analyze. (1) If you have installed a Windows theme, try to remove it. (2) Use Task Manager or the better [autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to disable installed startup items that might be connected to the Start menu or the display.

Comment: I'm using the default dark theme. I'll try disabling autostarting apps that I don't need to be running, but yeah, it will be hard to debug it this way. My biggest hope is that someone had this problem and solved it somehow. I found one similar question but it only had the solution I mentioned - restarting explorer/system.